# How to ask SWIG to rename nested structures differently?

Tags: c, swig

Say I have an `example.h` file with following:

```
struct foo_bar {
  int x;
};

struct foo {
  struct {
    int y;
  } bar;
};
```

and `example.i` with following:

```
%module example
%{
#include "example.h"
%}
%include "example.h"
```

Now, when I generate the SWIG wrapper, SWIG defines a new struct `foo_bar` to access the nested `bar` struct in `foo` (also [mentioned in the documentation](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nested_structs)). However this is causing `foo_bar` struct to be duplicated and it is failing the compilation.

So, how can I ask SWIG to use `foo2` when SWIG creates custom structs to access nested structs of `foo`, so that all nested structs for `foo` are created like `foo2_bar`? I tried `%rename` but it only renames the wrapper functions, not the custom structs created by SWIG to access nested structs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I'm doing a `find` throughout the C source code with `/\bfoo\b/` and `replace` it with `foo2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the advanced SWIG rename operator to selectively rename only nested classes, for example:

```
%rename("nestedprefix%s", %$isnested) "";
```

Will add 'nestedprefix' in front of the name of any nested type.

You could also use regex and fullname matching to convert `struct foo { struct bar {};};` to `foo_bar`:

```
%rename("%(regex:/.*?(::)?([^:]*)(::)?([^:]+)/\\2_\\4/)s", %$isnested, fullname=1) "";
```

(The regex might need some tweaking to match all the weird cases I haven't thought of).

For the specific case you showed with the anonymous inner class you could do something like:

```
%module test

%rename("%s_inner", %$isnested, match$name="foo_bar") "";

%inline %{
struct foo_bar {};

struct foo {
  struct {
    int x;
  } bar;
};
%}
```

This renames just the nested class that would otherwise be called `foo_bar`, but not the original `foo_bar`.

Alternatively:

```
%rename("%s_inner", %$isnested, %$classname="foo") "";
```

Matches inner classes with the parent class named `foo`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. As I mentioned that problem with `%rename` is that it only renames the wrapper functions that are created by SWIG to access those structs, not the name of the custom structs themselves which are created by SWIG for nested structs.

Comment: @vik My final example is renaming the struct itself in the test Java classes I ran it on. What language are you targeting?

Comment: I'm targeting Ruby. `%rename` does rename the struct but in the targeted language (by renaming the `_wrap` C functions), what I'm looking for is renaming the "C struct" in the `example_wrap.c` file itself (to avoid name collision as shown in the question).